# Merging CSV file with shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry, csv, attribute-joins

I have a CSV file with have `"ID"` which is repeating, something like:

```
ID     other values..
1       njhb
1       njhb
2       njhb
2       njhb
1       njhb
```

Anyway, I have in shapefile that `"ID"` which is unique (not repeating):

```
ID2      geoemetry
1          g1
2          g2

....
```

I want to merge that values, something like Descartes multiplication, so the output will be:

```
ID     other values..     ID2    geometry
1       njhb                1      g1
1       njhb                1      g1
2       njhb                2      g2
2       njhb                2      g2
1       njhb                1      g1
```

Join function in QGIS don't merge it, just take first corresponding value from each and join and rest ignores.

Comment: You need to go the otherway around. Choose your CSV as master and add the shapefile as joined layer. Since you have the geometry stored in a column this should be no problem.

Comment: I don't have it, that was only for example. I thing I am gonna use postgis. But I would like to know how to do it in QGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit tricky to do but you get your result.

First select your CSV and create a join to your shapefile. You will get all results but without geometry.

To fix that you can now create a new virtual field in your CSV.
Open your attribute table and start the field calculator. Choose `text`, `unlimited length (text)`, as field name choose `wkt_geom` ideally and enter the following code:

```
geom_to_wkt(geometry(get_feature('point2','id',attribute($currentfeature,'id'))))
```

`point2` is my shapefile layer; replace it with the name of your shapefile layer.

`id` is the matching field in my shapefile layer; replace it with your ID in your shapefile layer.

`attribute($currentfeature,'id')` is the matching field in my CSV layer; replace it with yours.

[image]

After you've done this, save your CSV as a new CSV. *(I'm not aware of a method to change geometry source of a already added CSV file; please correct me if there is one)*

Now you can import your new CSV with geometry. Do whatever you want with it, e.g. save it as shapefile or something else.

Comment: It is changed, I've lost some lines. :O

Comment: Is it possible to use increase precision, so I wouldn't lost those lines?

Comment: what lines did you loose? You will keep ALL data in your original CSV and just add the matching data and geometry of your shapefile. Check if all id's can be matched. Also check for field types of your matching-fields.

Comment: I checked, I have exact number of rows in csv file, probably don't every line have a pair in csv file. I lost about 10 lines. I can't control new shp file manually because i have 57k features. :D Is it posible just to select manually those 10 missing lines and add to a new shapefile?

Comment: Btw instead of that, everything is same. Geometry wasn't lost. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean. You lost lines of your original CSV? Or lines of the shapefile you wanted to match?

Comment: Some lines in original shp file doesen't have a match in csv file, so I lost that features. 
And like I said in question, the main aim was to connect all features. Now I want to add features which are missing (which are different geographically) from old one shapefile to a new one.

Comment: Btw Thank you for your time, I am really appreciate. :)

Comment: Yes, you will only keep those features that can be matched with the CSV. You need to edit your CSV and add the id's that are only inside the shapefile. Just create some dummy lines for that without any other data. Then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

The most fool proof way I've found to do this is by creating an attribute field in the shapefile containing the text result of `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`, joining the shapefile to the csv, exporting to a new csv to make the joined fields a permanent part of the data set and then creating a new delimited text layer from the new csv, pointing QGIS as the joined WKT geom column.

The other ways described were creating some issues for me.